# How much time does la4j should take for solving the linear equation of 50k*50k as A(sparse) and B as 50k to get X for AX=B

Tags: vector, matrix, linear-algebra

I am attaching the code for solving the sparse matrix but it seems that it is taking too much time for solving the equation. Please tell me if I am doing something wrong.

```
Code 1:
//given to the below function 
//int[] row_inds, int[] col_inds, double[] vals, double[] x, double[] b;

value=49152;
Matrix A= new CCSMatrix(value,value);
for(i=0;i<value;i++){
   A.set(row_inds[i], col_inds[i], val[i]);
}
Vector B = new BasicVector(b);
GaussianSolver solvers=new GaussianSolver(A);
Vector Y=solvers.solve(B, LinearAlgebra.SPARSE_FACTORY);
for (i = 0; i < Y.length(); i++) {
    x[i]=Y.get(i);
}

Code 2:
//given to the below function 
//int[] row_inds, int[] col_inds, double[] vals, double[] x, double[] b;
value=49152;
Matrix A= new CCSMatrix(value,value);
for(i=0;i<value;i++){
   A.set(row_inds[i], col_inds[i], val[i]);
}
Vector B = new BasicVector(b);
LinearSystemSolver solver = A.withSolver(LinearAlgebra.FORWARD_BACK_SUBSTITUTION);
Vector X = solver.solve(B, LinearAlgebra.SPARSE_FACTORY);
System.out.println("solved for vector X");
for (i = 0; i < X.length(); i++) {
   x[i]=X.get(i);
}
```

Comment: This issue is being discussed here: https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j/issues/150

Answer (score 0):

There was a performance bug in la4j. It has been fixed in [the last release](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j/releases/tag/0.5.0). It should work fine now (especially for sparse matrices with low density).